# Substituting a text variable into an awk statement

Tags: bash, awk

How do I get the following awk script to pass the username result of `whoami` to get stored in a variable and then called upon to search for that text with awk.  I seem to be able to pass $myCount but not $myUser

```
myUser=$(whoami)
myCount=6
awk -v count=$myCount -v Bob=$myUser '/"tg-6k2t".*Bob/{x=count}x--==1{sub(/tg-6k2t/,"tg-b5xm")}1' file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the value isn't your problem, trying to reference it inside a constant regexp is. Set `-v user="$myUser"` on the command line list like you're setting `count` and change:

```
/"tg-6k2t".*Bob/
```

to:

```
$0 ~ ("\"tg-6k2t\".*" user)
```

The parens aren't strictly necessary, just there to improve readability. You need to add `$0 ~` because the regexp literal `/foo/` on it's own in a conditional context is shorthand for `$0 ~ /foo/` but `"foo"` in a conditional context is just a test to see if a string is not null and you need to make it explicitly `$0 ~ "foo"` to make it a regexp comparison of $0 against a dynamic regexp.

You might want to consider making your whole script parameterized:

```
awk -v count="$myCount" -v user="$myUser" -v old='tg-6k2t' -v new='tg-b5xm' '
    $0 ~ ("\"" old "\".*" user){x=count} x--==1{sub(old,new)} 1
' file
```

Comment: Much better answer than mine